# Berkeley DB, Multithreaded FATAL ERROR

Tags: c++, c, berkeley-db

I wrote a program that uses the Berkeley DB in C/C++ like a mix.
I have one class called bdb with this method.

```
    int open(char *db_name)
 {

  flags = DB_CREATE;
  u_int32_t envCreateFlags = DB_CREATE |
                           DB_INIT_LOCK|
                           DB_INIT_LOG|
                           DB_INIT_MPOOL|
                           DB_INIT_TXN|
                           DB_RECOVER |
                           DB_THREAD;


  ret = db_env_create(&dbenv, 0);
        dbenv->err(dbenv,ret,"err db_env_create ");         
  ret = dbenv->open(dbenv,"./",envCreateFlags,0);
       dbenv->err(dbenv,ret,"err db_env_open ");     
  ret = db_create(&dbp,dbenv, 0);
dbp->err(dbp,ret,"err db_create ");     
  ret = dbp->open(dbp,        /* DB structure pointer */
                  NULL,       /* Transaction pointer */
                  db_name, /* On-disk file that holds the database. */
                  NULL,       /* Optional logical database name */
                  DB_BTREE,   /* Database access method */
                  flags,      /* Open flags */
                  0);         /* File mode (using defaults) */

dbp->err(dbp,ret,"err dbp open  ");     


  return ret;
 };
```

So next in the program I will use a method like

```
 int getEntry( char *url ,unsigned int *fp)
 {
  DBT key, data;

   DBC *cursorp;
   dbp->cursor(dbp, NULL, &cursorp, 0); 

   memset(&key, 0, sizeof(DBT));
   memset(&data, 0, sizeof(DBT));

   key.data = fp;
   key.ulen = sizeof(unsigned int);
   key.flags = DB_DBT_USERMEM;

   data.data = url;
   data.ulen = sizeof(char) * maxUrlSize;
   data.flags = DB_DBT_USERMEM;

   ret = cursorp->c_get(cursorp, &key,&data, DB_PREV);
  if (cursorp != NULL) 
   cursorp->close(cursorp); 


  if (ret == DB_NOTFOUND)
   return -1;
}
```

So, the object is created ones and than the adress is given to the multiple threads.
they all to getEntry and checkUpdate maybe on the same time..

the result is every time I get after the start of the program

```
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
```

And I get a Segmentation fault on the line

```
ret = cursorp->c_get(cursorp, &key,&data, DB_PREV);
```

I don't know why?

Comment: Can you run your program in a debugger to see where it actually fails, and also try boiling the code down to make a shorter example?

Comment: sure, u dont know how to make the code shorter without loosing information... :-/ hope its oki

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider posting your question to the [Berkeley DB Forum](http://bit.ly/eIREhr) on OTN. There is an active community of application developers, support engineers and BDB developers who interact on that forum.

Here are a couple of quick possibilities:

- Is it possible that your application is calling dbenv->open() in every thread? That would tend to produce the symptom that you describe. You only want to call dbenv->open once at the beginning of your application.
- You need to specify DB_THREAD when you open the database handle.

The following documentation may be useful: [Chapter 4](http://bit.ly/hEhDgg) of the C++ Getting Started Guide, the [Example](http://bit.ly/e8Gq3y) in the C++ Getting Started Guide, the [Programmer Notes](http://bit.ly/hBc7cA) chapter in the Reference GuideY.

If this doesn't resolve your question, I'd encourage you to post to the Berkeley DB forum listed above.